# How can I read version of project in dotnet core (formerly asp.net mvc6)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

how can I read assembly version information for my project, the value which in this case comes from the from project.json, and read that in my ASP.net core Controller and pass it to the view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In an early beta version you could add constructor to your controller with parameter `IApplicationEnvironment`. this param have a property with `Version` name

```
  public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment) {
        this.appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
  }
```

(No longer works in ASP.net core 1.0)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, in later versions and indeed in the released version this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Razor to get this right from the View and bypass the Controller.

```
    <b>Version</b> @(
            Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController))
                .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
                .InformationalVersion
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your application version, as it exists in project.json, you would write:

```
    string appVersion = Assembly.
      GetEntryAssembly().
     GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().
     InformationalVersion;
```

Additionally, if you want to know which version of .net core your app is running on you can do this:

```
....
  string dotNetRuntimeVersion = typeof(RuntimeEnvironment)
                        .GetTypeInfo()
                        .Assembly
                        .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
                        .InformationalVersion;
```

You may need to add these units to your using for the above runtime version snippet:

```
using Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions;
using System.Reflection;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` from your project's assembly and then pass it to the view.

Here's how to get that attribute: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/RuntimeEnvironment.cs#L35-L44

Comment: actually showing what to do is preferred on Stackoverflow instead of "read this link which is going to break later"